# Pass data via template argument, C++

Tags: c++, templates, range, variadic-templates, parameter-pack

I am thinking about having [color spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space) structs in my program. Now as you can see each color space has its limitations for each of its component. So consider a struct like this.

```
template<typename T>
struct SomeColorSpace{
    T component1,component2,.....; // or std::array<T,N> components, N is compile-time const
};
```

Now I need somehow define a range so I create a struct.

```
template<typename T>
struct Range{

    T min, max;

    // Some constructors initializing min and max...
};
```

Now I need my color space struct to know what is the range of each of its component. But as you see I can't just hold `std::array<Ranges<T>,N> ranges` in my struct as the ranges differ from type to type. As an example consider `struct RGB` each of the component may be `float` or `unsigned char` so when the components are `float` the ranges of each component becomes `[0,1];` and when it is unsigned char it is `[0,255];`. Writing template specialization for each of these case is a solution but instead I want a signature like this. `using RGBFloat = RGB<float,Range<float>...>`. I mean *I want to pass the ranges via template parameter pack*. I know that for instance `Range<float>(0,1);` is a non-type template parameter so one workaround is to refactor `struct Range` like this

```
template<typename T,T _MIN, T _MAX>
struct Range{
    static constexpr T MIN = _MIN;
    static constexpr T MAX = _MAX;
};
```

So I can pass `Range<T,T min, T max>` as template parameter pack, but then I have to do keep the pack in a `std::tuple`(I do not want this either). My question is do you see any other possibility via refactoring the `Range` struct or something else to have this signature of defining a color space. `using DefineColorSpace = ColorSpace<unsigned char, ranges....>`. I know that `C++ 20` has huge refactors for non-type template parameters , but I am using `clang` and it seem that they [do not support](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) that feature yet.
Any advice can be helpful, thanks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for literal classes as non-type template parameter is already in clang trunk. See it [live on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/dcn9fE):

```
template<typename T>
struct Range
{
    T min, max;
};

template<typename T, Range<T> R>
struct SomeColorSpace
{
    static constexpr Range<T> r = R;

    T component1, component2;
};

using Rgb = SomeColorSpace<float, Range<float>{0.0f, 1.0f}>;

auto test()
{
    Rgb color{0.4f, 0.1f};

    float c1 = color.component1;
    float min = Rgb::r.min;

    return Rgb::r.max;
}
```

So it will arrive soon in clang. Until then a possible workaround is to use traits. See it [live on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1oe189):

```
template<class T, class Trait>
struct SomeColorSpace
{
    static constexpr T min = Trait::min;
    static constexpr T max = Trait::max;

    T component1, component2;
};

struct RgbTrait
{
    static constexpr float min = 0.0f;
    static constexpr float max = 1.0f;
};

using Rgb = SomeColorSpace<float, RgbTrait>;

auto test()
{
    Rgb color{0.4f, 0.1f};

    float c1 = color.component1;
    float min = Rgb::min;

    return Rgb::max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear what you want, as for color, r/g/b/(a) would have same range depending on type.

So a simple traits allows to map minimum/maximum of `float` to `[0.f,1.f]` and `std::uint8_t` to `[0,255]`:

```
template <typename T> struct RangeTraits;

template <> struct RangeTraits<double>
{
    constexpr double min = 0.;
    constexpr double max = 1.;
};
template <> struct RangeTraits<std::uint8_t>
{
    constexpr std::uint8_t min = 0;
    constexpr std::uint8_t max = 255;
};
// ...
```

And

```
template <typename T>
struct SomeColorSpace{
    std::array<T, N> components;// N is compile-time constant

// use RangeTraits<T>::min, RangeTraits<T>::max when needed.
};
```

Another interpretation is that your template parameter are "just" default values for initialization:

```
template <typename T, T DefaultMin, T DefaultMax>
struct Range{
    T min = DefaultMin;
    T max = DefaultMax;

    // Some constructors initializing min and max...
};
```

but those default should be forget afterward

So you might be able to do something like:

```
std::array<Range<std::int8_t>, 2> components{Range<std::int8_t, 0, 127>, Range<std::int8_t, -10, 10>};
```

Then you might do:

```
template <typename T, T...> struct Range;

template <typename T>
struct Range<T>
{
    T min;
    T max;

    Range(T min, T max) : min(min), max(max) {}

    template <T Min, T Max,>
    Range(Range<T, Min, Max>& rhs) : min(rhs.min), max(rhs.max) {}

    Range(Range& rhs) = default;
    // ...
};

template <typename T, T Min, T Max>
struct Range<T, Min, Max>
{
    T min = Min;
    T max = Max;

    Range() = default;
    Range(Range& rhs) = default;

    // Possibly keep constructors of conversion and the one with runtime min/max
    // ...
};
```